# Do I need multiple AWS SNS platform applications for different device operating systems?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications

I'm new to the concept of push notifications and sending them from Amazons SNS service so apologies if this is a stupid question.

For our current app we are wanting to target both android and iOS devices. We've successfully created a platform application in SNS that uses firebase to target android devices.

We initial thought that we could use the same platform application for iOS as firebase supports pushing to iOS devices. However, the AWS documentation indicates that you have to create a separate platform application which uses APSN to push to iOS devices.

Is it the correct approach to have multiple SNS platform applications for each device operating system you're trying to target?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks David.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I’d provide the outcome we came to just in case anyone might find it useful. After looking into firebase it seemed an obvious choice for it to replace SNS. The notification side of firebase is free and much easier to integrate into our app as opposed to SNS where it seems you have to worry about multiple notification providers for each mobile platform. The documentation around firebase is a lot better than what is available for SNS.